# What are ShadowBands during SolarEclipse and how can it be reproduced?

Tags: earth, sun, moon, eclipse, shadow

I recently got to know about different phases of a solar eclipse and its impact on Earth and its living creatures.., but one of the most interesting and not well explained phenomenon is the ShadowBands appearance during Total Solar Eclipse in between c2 and mid phase (totality) and again between c3 and mid phase (totality).

This video is more expressive if someone wants to look into in any case

[The Shadow Band of 2016 Total Solar Eclipse in Indonesia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tiI6VWXqj4&t=0s)

I am hoping to get an explanation (theoretical and or practical) which can help reproduce it within a lab setup.